# Avoiding repeating equivalent lines

Tags: python

```py
def tokenized_dataset(self, dataset):
    tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

    print("\n"+"="*10, "Start Tokenizing", "="*10)
    start = time.process_time()
    train_articles = [self.encode(document, tokenizer) for document in dataset["train"]["article"]]
    test_articles = [self.encode(document, tokenizer) for document in dataset["test"]["article"]]
    val_articles = [self.encode(document, tokenizer) for document in dataset["val"]["article"]]
    train_abstracts = [self.encode(document, tokenizer) for document in dataset["train"]["abstract"]]
    test_abstracts = [self.encode(document, tokenizer) for document in dataset["test"]["abstract"]]
    val_abstracts = [self.encode(document, tokenizer) for document in dataset["val"]["abstract"]]

    print("Time:", time.process_time() - start)
    print("=" * 10, "End Tokenizing", "="*10+"\n")

    return {"train": (dataset["train"]["id"], train_articles, train_abstracts),
            "test": (dataset["train"]["id"], test_articles, test_abstracts),
            "val": (dataset["val"]["id"], val_articles, val_abstracts)}
```

I have this code and I've just realized that I repeat the code 6 times or equivalently, i.e. `[self.encode(document, tokenizer) for document in dataset...]`. Is there a way to change the block of 6 equivalent lines by something more natural and less repetitive?

Comment: just create a function, that is what they are for, aren't they?

Comment: `def stuff(x,y): return [self.encode(document, tokenizer) for document in dataset[x][y]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this by using python functions.

```
def get_values(x,y):
    return [self.encode(document, tokenizer) for document in dataset[x][y]]
```